# How to multiple cut one picture in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to multiple cut one picture in c# code.the following image is my c # forum and I can select an area and cut it.

[image]I want to multiple cut one picture in c# code
I want to repeat this process
     private void btnKes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int tiklanma = 0;
                if (true)
                {
                    tiklanma++;
                }
                pictureBox2.Refresh();

```
            pictureBox2.Refresh();

            Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            Graphics g = pictureBox2.CreateGraphics();

            int x1, x2, y1, y2;

            Int32.TryParse(txtX1.Text, out x1);
            Int32.TryParse(txtX2.Text, out x2);
            Int32.TryParse(txtY1.Text, out y1);
            Int32.TryParse(txtY2.Text, out y2);


            if ((x1 < x2 && y1 < y2))
            {
                rectCropArea = new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
            }
            else if (x2 < x1 && y2 > y1)
            {
                rectCropArea = new Rectangle(x2, y1, x1 - x2, y2 - y1);
            }
            else if (x2 > x1 && y2 < y1)
            {
                rectCropArea = new Rectangle(x1, y2, x2 - x1, y1 - y2);
            }
            else
            {
                rectCropArea = new Rectangle(x2, y2, x1 - x2, y1 - y2);
            }

            pictureBox1.Refresh(); // This repositions the dashed box to new location as per coordinates entered.
            int sayac = 40;

            for (int i = 0; i < tiklanma; i++)
            {

                PictureBox pcBx = new PictureBox();
                Size size = new Size(100, 100);
                pcBx.Location();

                pcBx.Size = size;

                g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, rectCropArea.Width, rectCropArea.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            sourceBitmap.Dispose();
        }
```

I want to select the fields more than once in the second picture and save the fields. How can I do this?[image]
[image]

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Use a `FlowLayoutPanel`, and every time you draw a new segment on the main image add a new `PictureBox` control to the layout panel.

Eventually you'll want to do other things with these picture segments, and so I also recommend immediately going a for a custom/user control here that includes a PictureBox as one part. That will make it much easier later to use buttons or context with each picture.

The specifics for all of this are out of scope for this type of question. We'd need to see more of your code to be able to use appropriate context with our answer, and the results are more than can fit well in the simple Q&A format. So go, try what you can, and then come back and ask new questions when you run into more specific problems.